# Selenium InternetExplorer webdriver not run

Tags: java, selenium

I'd like to run my selenium tests in Internet Explorer but the IE WebDriver not run well. If I pressed the delete button then I got a confirmation popup and in this case, the webdriver loose the control

- Selenium version: 2.39.0
- jUnit version: 4.11
- Internet Explorer: 10

Has anyone an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Is it enabled in all modes? Also, you won't have much luck anyway - Selenium doesn't support IE11.

Comment: Oh, nice... But at least I know the reason of my problem :) Then I will downgrade to IE10. Thanks